# delphi xe5 + Android exceção RSConnectionClosedGracefully, a troco de nada

Tags: android, exceção, delphi-xe5

Já contornei vários bugs no XE5 + Android, mas esse está me derrubando. O sistema gera espontaneamente a exceção `RSConnectionClosedGracefully`, a troco de nada. O mesmíssimo código roda tranquilo no Windows.

Alguém conhece alguma dica de como contornar essa bronca? (não adianta capturar a exceção, pq o sistema deixa de comunicar-se; não adianta dexiar de gerar, pq o sistema cai; ...)

Comment: Uma sugestão: http://mlogcat.tistory.com/1

Comment: Outra: ...android-sdk\tools\monitor.bat

Comment: Tente capturar o erro diretamente pelo log (com as aplicações acima) talvez terá uma dica sobre o problema.

Answer (score 0):

O problema foi contornado.

Agradeço às sugestões, e vou examiná-las pois podem ser úteis em novas  situações.

A solução: cada vez que vou enviar alguma coisa para o servidor, destruo os objetos do INdy e reconstruo. Não interferiu no desempenho do aplicativo, mas não sei ainda se com a continuação vai aparecer algum outro problema.